# Show that f(x)= $x^{\frac{-1}{2}}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ with $f(0)=0$ is integrable on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Show that

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^{\frac{-1}{2}}\sin(\frac{1}{x}) , & 0 <x\leq 1 \\
      0  , & x=0 \end{cases}$

is integrable on $[0,1]$. Integrable means that $\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]} |f(x)|\,\mathrm dx < \infty$.

My attempt:

First, I checked to see if $f(x)$ had a bounded derivative on $[0,1]$. If it did, then it would be a Lipschitz function, hence absolutely continuous and hence integrable. Unfortunately, the derivative is not bounded.

Okay, so then I noticed that if $0 < a \leq 1$ then $f(x)$ is a well defined continuous function and so Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, and hence Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$.

Next, I need to figure out how to prove that $f$ is continuous. I wouldn't mind some help with this part. Then I have that $\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+} f(a)=f(0)$.

So, $$f(1)-f(0) = \lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+} f(1)-f(a) = \lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{[a,1]} f(x)\,\mathrm dx = \lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+} \int_a^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Ugh idk honestly I'm lost. Would appreciate help. I'm pretty slow so lots of details appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it like $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|\,\mathrm dx\leq\int_{0}^{1}x^{-1/2}\,\mathrm dx=2<\infty$.

Comment: why is it obvious that $f(x) \leq x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$?

Comment: $|\sin u|\leq 1$ no matter what.

Comment: Hm... Is it really this simple??? No other justification needed?? It was a question on a test and I think prof wanted us to use dominated convergence theorem

Comment: I missed the absolute sign to the $f$. It suffices to check for the absolute integrand, and bound it by less than $\infty$, that's it.

Comment: How do we know we can compare it to the Riemann integral like this? Sry if stupid question

Comment: I don't understand your question? Can you paraphrase?

Comment: The original integral I'm asked to evaluate is a Lebesgue integral. You show it's integrable by saying it's less than or equal to a Riemann integrable. What makes them comparable here?

Comment: Note that Riemann integrable function is itself Lebesgue integrable and the values are equal. Also that nonnegative improper Riemann interable function is also Lebesgue integrable with the same value again.

Comment: There are cases when they arn't the same, but alas.

Comment: For nonnegative functions, Lebesgue and Improper Riemann are the same, so feel free to do anything to the integrals.